# NPM : Configure to use github oauth token

Tags: npm, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to deploy using AWS code build and have an NPM dependency which exists in a private github repository only.

When using composer for similar scenarios I use the "github-oauth" option https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#github-oauth. Is there similar functionality for NPM without hard-coding my token into my package.json file?